# How to control the bar width of a grouped bar chart in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**data**

```
structure(list(MutationsType = c("0:homdel:0-100kb", "1:LOH:1Mb-10Mb", 
"1:LOH:1Mb-10Mb", "1:LOH:10Mb-40Mb", "0:homdel:0-100kb", "1:LOH:0-100kb", 
"0:homdel:100kb-1Mb", "0:homdel:0-100kb", "1:LOH:0-100kb", "0:homdel:0-100kb", 
"1:LOH:10Mb-40Mb", "1:LOH:10Mb-40Mb", "0:homdel:100kb-1Mb", "1:LOH:0-100kb", 
"0:homdel:100kb-1Mb", "1:LOH:100kb-1Mb", "1:LOH:100kb-1Mb", "1:LOH:10Mb-40Mb", 
"0:homdel:0-100kb", "1:LOH:0-100kb", "1:LOH:1Mb-10Mb", "1:LOH:100kb-1Mb", 
"1:LOH:10Mb-40Mb", "0:homdel:>1Mb", "0:homdel:100kb-1Mb", "0:homdel:100kb-1Mb", 
"1:LOH:1Mb-10Mb", "1:LOH:0-100kb", "0:homdel:100kb-1Mb", "0:homdel:>1Mb", 
"1:LOH:0-100kb", "0:homdel:100kb-1Mb", "1:LOH:1Mb-10Mb", "0:homdel:>1Mb", 
"0:homdel:0-100kb", "0:homdel:>1Mb", "1:LOH:0-100kb", "0:homdel:0-100kb", 
"0:homdel:0-100kb", "0:homdel:>1Mb", "0:homdel:>1Mb", "1:LOH:1Mb-10Mb", 
"1:LOH:1Mb-10Mb", "1:LOH:0-100kb", "1:LOH:100kb-1Mb", "1:LOH:1Mb-10Mb", 
"1:LOH:1Mb-10Mb", "0:homdel:>1Mb", "0:homdel:0-100kb"), CN = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), Type = c("homdel", 
"homdel", "homdel", "homdel", "homdel", "homdel", "homdel", "homdel", 
"homdel", "homdel", "homdel", "homdel", "homdel", "homdel", "homdel", 
"homdel", "homdel", "homdel", "homdel", "homdel", "homdel", "LOH", 
"LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", 
"LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", 
"LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH", "LOH"
), Size = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("0-100kb", "100kb-1Mb", 
">1Mb", "1Mb-10Mb", "10Mb-40Mb", ">40Mb"), class = "factor"), 
    MutSig = c("CCN1", "CCN2", "CCN3", "CCN4", "CCN5", "CCN6", 
    "CCN7", "CCN1", "CCN2", "CCN3", "CCN4", "CCN5", "CCN6", "CCN7", 
    "CCN1", "CCN2", "CCN3", "CCN4", "CCN5", "CCN6", "CCN7", "CCN1", 
    "CCN2", "CCN3", "CCN4", "CCN5", "CCN6", "CCN7", "CCN1", "CCN2", 
    "CCN3", "CCN4", "CCN5", "CCN6", "CCN7", "CCN1", "CCN2", "CCN3", 
    "CCN4", "CCN5", "CCN6", "CCN7", "CCN1", "CCN2", "CCN3", "CCN4", 
    "CCN5", "CCN6", "CCN7"), Contribution = c(5.19e-06, 1.3e-07, 
    1.9e-07, 0.08029968, 4e-08, 9.22e-05, 7e-08, 0.01464032, 
    0.00180809, 1.5e-07, 0.05639156, 0.00649378, 1.9e-07, 0.00031971, 
    0.01814325, 0.00706934, 1.3e-07, 0.00210131, 0.00096393, 
    0.00031971, 0.00051292, 0.00707025, 0.00075506, 0.03741672, 
    0.01814325, 0.00149914, 9.22e-05, 1.1e-07, 0.02898539, 0.00051292, 
    1.556e-05, 0.01435299, 0.01814325, 7.439e-05, 0.00048986, 
    1.5e-07, 0.00149914, 7.439e-05, 7.913e-05, 0.03741672, 0.01435299, 
    0.00707025, 0.00031971, 0.00740625, 0.02898539, 1.7e-06, 
    0.01435299, 1.9e-07, 9.22e-05), Race = c("CBCGA", "CBCGA", 
    "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", 
    "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", 
    "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", 
    "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", 
    "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", 
    "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", 
    "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA", "CBCGA"), Type2 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("homdel:0", "LOH:1", "LOH:2", "LOH:3-4", 
    "LOH:5-8", "LOH:9+", "het:2", "het:3-4", "het:5-8", "het:9+"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -49L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have drawn a grouped bar chart using the data above with the following code.

```
ggplot(tmpdf, aes(x = Type2, y = Contribution, fill = Size)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = 'dodge', width = 0.8) + 
  scale_x_discrete('') + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.25),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_line(size = 0.25),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10))
```

And I got a bar chart below. We can see that the bar width of the first group "homodel:0" was different from the width of the second group due to different levels of the fill variable. **I want to know how to control the bar width in this condition and make them the same between two groups.**
[image]